# why is some of the question blurred in Stackoverflow?

Tags: support

i noticed today, some of the question in StackOverflow newest tab  is  blurred. Is there some reason for this? am i missing something?

[image]

Comment: At a glance, my guess is that you are ignoring either the `windows-8` and `node.js` tags, or the `javascript` tag.

Comment: yes.. the javascript tag... :).. i had nothing in my ignored list before...so i never saw this blurred question before... javascript got added by mistake i guess... so i was wondering what is this... anyways thanks.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The questions use one or more tags that you have in your "Ignored Tags" list.

Comment: How do I check my ignore list ?